# download a local file, on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi there I'm trying to download a local file on button click in VueJs

```html
<a href="./documentation.docx" download>Download</a>
```

I have the documentation in the same folder as index

But when I'm trying to download, its saying `No File`

Comment: Browser are not allowed to access the local file system unless the page runs in `file://` protocol. Or what do you mean by "local file"?

Comment: Set full path of your documentation.docx file to href

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local file access with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: @connexo Yes the system doesn't allow that and By local file I mean that the document is in my assets, idk how should i say that,

Comment: @Hard_Coder it doesn't allow to do that, it doesn't let file://

Comment: Of course, run your app through a webpack dev server. Also, the `local file` OP was talking about was probably in comparison vs a `hosted` resource on the web. Here, he does have the asset in his code repo.

Comment: @Albandenica You can see my solution for a method that allows you to trigger a download using any element - not just an `a` tag. You can bind this method to anything with `@click` or `@click.native`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work properly as you've written it. It's essentially comes down to the given path, try something like this structure and this code (with an absolute path):

```html
<a href="/azuki.jpg" download> download stuff </a>
```

[image]

Also, check the official documentation page here: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder